# tshark: apply filter then output a fixed number of packets

Tags: command-line, packet-capture, tshark

I would like to use one tshark command that would: open a capture file, apply a filter to its contents and then output a fixed number of resulting packets. Currently, I have come up with

`tshark -r <infile> -Y <display filter>  -w <outfile> -c <number of packets>`

The problem is that `-c <number of packets>` works before the display filter is applied, i.e. it applies the `<display filter>` to the first `<number of packets>` of the original capture file which is *not* what I want. How do I reverse the order? I've been reading the manpage with no luck so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TShark:
tshark -r server_01.pcapng -l -Y dns > tshark  -c 100 -w server_01_dns100.pcapng